# How to insert query result to mysql array

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to add this `command.CommandText` result to `command2.CommandText` instead "result"

```
string connString = "connect data;";

MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
MySqlCommand command1 = conn.CreateCommand();
MySqlCommand command2 = conn.CreateCommand();

command.CommandText = "SELECT `order_id` FROM `test` WHERE `order_item_type`='line_item' AND `order_offer_send`='0';";
command2.CommandText = "SELECT `meta_value` FROM `test1` WHERE `order_item_id`='" + result + "'";
```

Comment: First of all, please parameterize your Queries, like this: [Working with Parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html) ! Second: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

i would work with parameters to avoid SQL Injection attacks and using directive to avoid open connections and a better usage of the gc:

```
string connString = "connect data;";
string Command = "SELECT `order_id` FROM `test` WHERE `order_item_type`='line_item' AND `order_offer_send`= @order_offer_send limit 1;";
string Command2 = "SELECT `meta_value` FROM `test1` WHERE `order_item_id`= @result limit 1"; 
int OfferID = -1;
string meta_value = null;
using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    mConnection.Open();
    using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(Command, mConnection))
    {
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@order_offer_send", "0"));
        OfferID = (int)myCmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(Command2, mConnection))
    {
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@result", OfferID));
        meta_value = (string)myCmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Comment: An other function to get the order for an order_offer_send would be even better. +1 for using by the way.

Comment: you're right, probably this can be done even with a join within one select

Comment: Yeah that would be another option, probably a better one unless there were some re-use opportunities. I was thinking more replacing OfferID in the second query with a function to get it.